# Why I can't retrieve my mongodb collection on my domain while I am able to do it on my local

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am working on a Vuejs(v3) project. While I can retrieve the data from my Mongodb collection on my local I can't do it for a specific domain name.

**index.js file**

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const cors = require('cors')
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid')
const multer = require('multer')
require('dotenv').config({ path: '../.env' })

const app = express()
app.use(cors())

const CONNECTION_STRING = process.env.CONNECTION_STRING
const DATABASENAME = process.env.DATABASENAME

function find (name, query, response) {
  mongoose.connection.db.collection(name, function (err, collection) {
     collection.find(query).toArray((error, result) => {
      response.send(result)
    });
 });
}

app.listen(5038 || 3000, () => {
  mongoose
    .connect(CONNECTION_STRING, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      dbName: DATABASENAME,
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Connected to the Database.')
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error(err))
})

app.get('/api/blogpage/getarticles', (request, response) => {
  find('articlescollection', {}, response)
})
```

I run `axios.get("https://domainname/" + 'api/blogpage/getarticles')`

and I see;

**headers**

```
Request URL:https://www.domainname/api/blogpage/getarticles
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
```

**preview**
`We're sorry but mevn-app doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.`

**response**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
        <title>mevn-app</title>
        <script defer="defer" src="/js/chunk-vendors.95815946.js"></script>
        <script defer="defer" src="/js/app.dfb1db13.js"></script>
        <link href="/css/chunk-vendors.ab6e52a4.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/css/app.897c0abf.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <noscript>
            <strong>We're sorry but mevn-app doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
        </noscript>
        <div id="app"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried various steps to solve but I couldn't. Probably I am missing a point but I don't know what is it...

Comment: Looks like you've got some SPA-style URL rewriting going on there (where any request to a virtual path is rewritten to `index.html`). This might be something you set up with your hosting provider since I don't see anything relevant in your Express code

Comment: In my opinion, it's related to the MongoDB permission, etc. I tried to allow access from everywhere but it didn't help. Can I handle the problem by declaring my domain's IP address to the MongoDB network accesses?

Comment: No, it's got nothing to do with MongoDB. You're making a request to your API but something is intercepting that and returning an HTML page. The request is not even reaching your Express route

Comment: I get it. I use Vercel. Do you have any idea about what I should do in there? I added env variables as I used in my local project except I changed the API_URL as my domain.